# appending a json data with a list from another json

Tags: python, json

```
var_data = {
        "a" : [ {
        "b" : {
            "c": [
                    {
                        "d": [
                            {
                                "e": {
                                    "f": "hello"
                                    
                                }
                               
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]

}
        }]
    }
```

i want to append var_data with a list under "d" array(y list). The list will be taken from another json(request json from POST in flask). below is the request json

```
{
    "a": "bcd",
    
    "w": [
        {
            "e": {
                "f": "hello"
            },
            "y": [
                {
                    
                    "z": "123"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

also if the input field is an empty y array like "y": [] the var_data should also have the empty array "y":[]
have tried the below
took the array from the request in tobeappended_list

```
tobeappended_list=request_data["w"][0]["y"]
```

then

```
for j in range(len(tobeappended_list)):
        var_data["a"][0]["b"]["c"][0]["d"][0].append(tobeappended_list[j]["y"])
```

However it is throwing error like append is not a method for dictionary

**EDITED**

desired var_data

```
var_data = {
        "a" : [ {
        "b" : {
            "c": [
                    {
                        "d": [
                            {
                                "e": {
                                    "f": "hello"
                                    
                                },
                                "y": [
                {
                    
                    "z": "123"
                }
            ]
                               
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]

}
        }]
    }
```

Comment: Can you post an an example of what you want the final dictionary to look like?

Comment: Indeed, you can't use `append()` with dict. This `var_data["a"][0]["b"]["c"][0]["d"][0]` should return a list, otherwise you need to first create an empty list `var_data["a"][0]["b"]["c"][0]["d"][0] = []` before calling `append()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can't use `append()` with dictionaries. This `var_data["a"][0]["b"]["c"][0]["d"][0]` should return a list.

Here's a solution to your problem after your update and your comment.

```
tobeappended_list=request_data["w"][0]["y"]

var_data["a"][0]["b"]["c"][0]["d"][0]["y"] = []

for j in range(len(tobeappended_list)):
    var_data["a"][0]["b"]["c"][0]["d"][0]["y"].append(tobeappended_list[j])
```

Comment: thanks I will try this out. also i need "y" :[] if the input is also "y":[] or empty array

Comment: I am getting key error "y" in the line var_data["a"][0]["b"]["c"][0]["d"][0] = [tobeappended_list[j]["y"] for j in range(len(tobeappended_list))]

Comment: Try my last update instead.

Comment: i will try this. One small issue that i see is if the input has not y list(no presence of y ), the output styill will have "y":[]